# Package upgrade hangs forever on mysql-apt-configure

Tags: apt, updates, mysql, mint

Yesterday it got stuck with an update for MySql. The `mysql-apt-config` didn't finish for ours so I had to shut down the machine in the end.

Today it suggested the same update again, but told me that I had to use `dpkg --configure -a` to fix the package first. When I do this it again hangs:

```
# sudo dpkg --configure -a
mysql-apt-config (0.3.3-1debian7) wird eingerichtet ..
```

Last line in german means roughly "[...] is getting prepared ...".

I've also tried to remove the mysql package with `apt-get purge mysql` - but this leads to the same result. It again hangs at the same step.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Same problem here. Seems to be something wrong in the package. Currently trying to find out exactly whats happening or if I can uninstall it since it blocks other updates. xP

Comment: I wouldn't consider this off-topic. It affects a lot of Ubuntu users.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had got the same problem a few hours ago. First I've killed the stuck process (kill -9 PID, or complete restart) then I completely uninstalled mysql.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
```

This will uninstall all mysql related packages, what is in most cases a bit overkill...

Be careful to make a copy of your databases before do this or simply don't delete the database when the uninstall process asks about it.
Then restart again (or kill the process of mysql-apt-config) and remove the mysql-apt-config package.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-apt-config
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After these steps I installed again everything solved the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

I'm not sure but probably it's enough to reinstall only mysql-apt-config. Good luck guys!

Comment: This works. I first missed the second part of your answer (removing mysql-apt-config), but this then seems to have done the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Simply purging mysql-apt-config and installing it from scratch worked for me here too.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-apt-config` or on any other command ubuntu says me to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but running `dpkg` the mysql-apt-config just stucks on the question "Which server version do you wish to receive?", does not matter which option I choose it still continue asking to choose one option of three: mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7-dmr, none. How can I remove the package at this point?

Comment: finally found the solution here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154067/could-not-select-ok-in-mysql-apt-config-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Restart didn't work for me. But `pkill mysql` let the update process to continue configuring other softwares and then I could purge mysql.