# mysql-server-5.7 configure fails

Tags: dpkg, mysql, configure

mysql-server-5.7 doesn't want to configure.

```
root@me-device:~# dpkg --configure mysql-server-5.7
Настраивается пакет mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) …
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 mysql-server-5.7
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

I tried to [Package upgrade hangs forever on mysql-apt-configure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593007/package-upgrade-hangs-forever-on-mysql-apt-configure) , also did rm -rf to /var/mysql but it didnt help

UPD-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

~$ systemctl status mysql.service

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Вт 2016-07-26 22:04:23 MSK; 8s ago
  Process: 28844 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 28840 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 28844 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 28845 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─28845 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─28889 sleep 1

июл 26 22:04:23 mcfinley-Lenovo-G570 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
июл 26 22:04:26 mcfinley-Lenovo-G570 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

~$ journalctl -xe

```
...
июл 26 22:04:54 mcfinley-Lenovo-G570 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
июл 26 22:04:54 mcfinley-Lenovo-G570 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
июл 26 22:04:54 mcfinley-Lenovo-G570 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
июл 26 22:04:54 mcfinley-Lenovo-G570 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Завершена остановка юнита mysql.service.
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Процесс остановки юнита mysql.service был завершен.
июл 26 22:04:54 mcfinley-Lenovo-G570 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Начинается запуск юнита mysql.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Начат процесс запуска юнита mysql.service.
июл 26 22:04:56 mcfinley-Lenovo-G570 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
июл 26 22:05:24 mcfinley-Lenovo-G570 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита mysql.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Произошел сбой юнита mysql.service.
-- 
-- Результат: failed.
...
```

(few times)

~$ cat /var/log/mysql/error.log

```
2016-07-26T19:06:56.952853Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2016-07-26T19:06:56.952958Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.952978Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.952991Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953001Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953012Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953022Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953033Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953043Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953053Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953063Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953073Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953083Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953093Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953103Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953113Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953123Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953133Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953143Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953153Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953162Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953172Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953182Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953192Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953201Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953211Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953221Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953231Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953240Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953250Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953259Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953269Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953278Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953288Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953297Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953307Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953454Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-07-26T19:06:56.953647Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-07-26T19:06:57.054097Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2016-07-26T19:06:57.054506Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 160726 22:06:57
2016-07-26T19:06:58.697424Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2526706
2016-07-26T19:06:58.702990Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2016-07-26T19:06:58.703029Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-07-26T19:06:58.703068Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-07-26T19:06:58.703083Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2016-07-26T19:06:58.703096Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2016-07-26T19:06:58.703108Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-07-26T19:06:58.703228Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2016-07-26T19:06:58.703240Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2016-07-26T19:06:58.703602Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2016-07-26T19:06:58.704157Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

(also few times)

Comment: What do `systemctl status mysql.service` and `journalctl -xe` say? How about the log: what does `/var/log/mysql/error.log` say?

Comment: Thak you for your reply! Added this information to post @robie-basak

Comment: I think you're missing log entries. Have you gone back far enough to cover the startup attempt?